# Identify Selected Row in  "GridViewCellEditEndedEvent" using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I am using a **WPF application with MVVM model**. I want to know how to get the **selected row** in telerik grid **GridViewCellEditEndedEvent** using C#.

Can any one please post some sample code or give me some suggestion on this?

Thanks in advance

My Code is :

```
      public void CellEdit(GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
      {
      if (e.EditAction == GridViewEditAction.Cancel)
      {
          return;
      }

      RadGridView Grid = (RadGridView)e.Source;
      var selectedItem = (MyViewModel)Grid.SelectedItem;
      // Here i want to get the selected row
      ..........
      ..........
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the edited row via the edited Cell and the ExtensionMethod `ParentOfTypeExtensions.ParentOfType` like this:

```
GridViewRow gridrow = e.Cell.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
```

And don't forget the using:

```
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
```